# Font does not show up correctly in mobile phone

Tags: html, css, fonts

I tried to load a font in HTML both in TTF and, via conversion tools, WOFF and WOFF2. It shows up in my laptop, but not correctly in my mother's phone (using Chrome):

```html
<script rel="preload" src="https://violetscript.github.io/docs/fonts/cour.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin></script>
```

I did also try CSS `@font` syntax with TTF and it still didn't show up in the phone's web browser. The font shows different from desktop.

The font in question is Courier New, extracted from Windows' `C:/Windows/Fonts` path.

#### Previous `@font-face`

Here's the previous `@font-face` attempt:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Courier New';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url('https://violetscript.github.io/docs/fonts/cour.woff2') format('woff2');
}
```

#### Working Snippet using `<script/>`

```css
html, body {
  font-family: 'Courier New';
  font-size: 64px;
}
```

```html
<script rel="preload" src="https://violetscript.github.io/docs/fonts/cour.woff2" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin></script>

undefined
```

#### Working Snippet using CSS `@font-face`

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Courier New';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url('https://violetscript.github.io/docs/fonts/cour.woff2') format('woff2');
}

html, body {
  font-family: 'Courier New';
  font-size: 64px;
}
```

```html
undefined
```

Interestingly, if you replace `cour.woff2` by `verdana.woff2`, it'll successfully change the font appearance to Verdana, even if `body { font-family: 'Courier New' }`, so my `@font-face` just works.

#### What the font looks like

It should show up text exactly like this:

[image: cour]

If you change the `@font-face`'s URL to `verdana.woff2` file, you'll see this:

[image: verdana]

#### Changing `@font-face` to point to Verdana

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Courier New';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url('https://violetscript.github.io/docs/fonts/verdana.woff2') format('woff2');
}

html, body {
  font-family: 'Courier New';
  font-size: 64px;
}
```

```html
undefined
```

Comment: You need to post a working sample of your issue. can you create a snippet with the @font declaration you tried as well? If the font is coming from windows, you probably need to declare a font-face as well.

Comment: @RicardoSilva Right, I added the `@font-face` sample and a snippet.

Answer (score 1):

I can't really be sure it works. But as far as I know [this is how you declare a font-face](https://codepen.io/rssilvaba/pen/vYzKzYY) from CSS.

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Cour2';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: url('https://violetscript.github.io/docs/fonts/cour.woff2') format('woff2');
}

html {
  font-family: 'Cour2';
}
```

Let me know if the font shows correctly.

Still do not rely on users downloading your fonts. always add fallbacks that work on any device, for example for Courier New you can:

```css
html {
  font-family: 'Cour2, Courier New, monospace';
}
```

Comment: Yep, in the `@font-face` example I just forgot to change from `truetype` to `woff2`, but it seems the browser ignored the `format()` specifier. I've noted that because I replaced `cour.woff2` by `verdana.woff2` and I successfully put Verdana in place of Courier New (yes, even with `html { font-family: 'Courier New' }`). So I'm sure my `@font-face` in the original question works; I'm just not sure about the `<script/>` one.

Comment: I've commented that in the question.